# Can I write and leverage memecached from different server processes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, go, memcached

Say you have a rails app, and you're already using queueing (resque) to offload some slow/non-urgent processing on the server.  That queueing processing performs some functionality need for the rails app - and then saves information into a memecached store...  Everything is good.

But is it possible to write a component triggered by queueing that runs a go application that, in turn, leverages the same underlying database as the rails app and writes to the same in-memory store?

Is this common? Not so trivial?  The database schema would be familiar to both rails and go, and while the go app might have some duplication of business logic, it's pretty siloed.  Think of it as a way to gradually migrate some server functionality running in rails to running in go.  Is this done in practice?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty common to have multiple encapsulated applications interact with a shared data store like memcached. This is fine to do in practice and which technology each of the apps is written in doesn't matter, just as long as they can access the store. In such an environment you may require some additional business logic to coordinate reads and writes which shouldn't be overlooked because it could become a lot of work.